# Definition error after updating Typescript to 1.5.3

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

I`ve updated my project from Typescript 1.4 to 1.5.3. Although I updated all definition packages via Nuget , I get this error.

```
Error   6   Cannot find name 'AudioContext'.    C:/Projects/Presenter/Scripts/typings/webaudioapi/waa.d.ts  13  13  MST.Engine

Error   1   Cannot find name 'AudioContext'.    C:/Projects/Presenter2/Scripts/typings/threejs/three.d.ts   5116    18 MST.Engine
```

I use THREE.Js definition files and waa.d.ts is a dependency of Three.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got it. It was still using tsc.exe V1.4 although I have updated to Typescript 1.5.3 . I updated project and PATH in enviroment variables and now it works.